# VBA to Send Email

Tags: excel, vba

thanks in advance for reading. Complete VBA novice here.

I have an Excel sheet which has an IF function: "=IF(D7>E1,TRUE,FALSE)". What I'd like to do is have Excel send an email if the cell shows TRUE and do nothing if it's FALSE. I can find various examples of VBA sending emails based on a numerical entry and a text entry, but putting in an IF function seems to stop it from working. Anyone got a brilliant bit of code to help me out please?

Also, if anyone has any recommendations for good online tutorials for a VBA beginner, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: This website is geared more towards people who have some code but have a problem with it rather than writing code from scratch. Also if you are a beginner, you are jumping in the deep end somewhat. Read [ask].

Comment: Thanks SJR, didn't realise that, must have missed that statement in the website info somewhere, but I've looked on so many of them this morning! Appreciate I'm in at the deep end, that's why I asked if anyone could recommend some good tutorials. It's landed on me as I'm the most likely candidate in the company to be able to find the right answer. Lucky me eh!

Comment: There are quite a few other websites where you can ask for code as I'm sure you have discovered. Ron de Bruin is usually the go-to website for VBA email questions.

Comment: Your first port of call should be your Internet Search Engine.  Searching for 'Excel VBA Send Email' returned https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm , depending on whether you want to send via Outlook and what exactly you want to send you may want to customise your Search Request.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the email part, to trigger a vba function within a in-cell function you write as:

```
=IF(G7<F7,fnTest(),FALSE)
```

You need Alt-F11 to display the VBA Editor. right-click the 'Microsoft Excel Objects' and INSERT > MODULE.

Then insert your email code in like my simple function below.

If you duplicate this example, and it work, when TRUE a message box will pop-up and you will know the reference to the function is working.  Then you can focus on the email code.

```
Public Function fnTest()
    MsgBox "TEST"
End Function
```